# How to insert footer dynamically in exported word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, lotus-notes

I have Lotus Notes web application that exports data into Microsoft Word (Version 2003) document. Data will be more than 10 pages. Now I want to insert a footer to display some text on each page. Suggestions please...

Comment: Have you tried something before posting your request?

Comment: Hi Seraphim, some times add comments link is not working for me. That's why i edited your comment and added my response. Sorry for that. I was able to set Page properties in lotus sciprt.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your question regards Lotus Notes, so my approach is no useful and I deleted my response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the Microsoft Developer Network.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194465.aspx) deals with the headers and footers.  You should be able to work it out from the examples given.

In addition, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923%28v=office.11%29.aspx) will come in handy for finding out the enumerated values of those constants